# Media Query is not firing in google dev console

Tags: css

I am trying to make my columns stack on each other when in mobile view so using a media query to trigger the scss when it is below 500px but for some reason in the scss when i am in responsive view it is not triggering under 500px. Here is my current code, i am currently using js and react to build this web app.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
  .mobile-view{
    flex-direction: column;  
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: You probably have a syntax error in the scss before that line. Anything after the error will not trigger. I think Odoug4 suggestions in his response are good

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out exactly what needs to be done based on your question but have you tried isolating the issue? If not, try making that media query change something you 100% know will work such as the background colour and if that works then it must be an issue with that piece of CSS. Otherwise, have you tried possibly trying it in a different browser or on an actual mobile device?